# Flutter / Dart cannot find java and $JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, dart, intellij-idea

I am following the [official tutorial on flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive) but I get the following error when clicking "run" in IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

If I run the `flutter doctor -v` you can see that it's installed:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.22.1 at /home/forest/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (11 days ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
    • Dart version 2.10.1

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /home/forest/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/forest/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /home/forest/.jdks/jdk1.8.0_261/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
```

(I have installed android studio from IDEA toolbox though.)

and from the shell I can run both commands:

```
forest@forest-PC:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/forest/.jdks/jdk1.8.0_261
forest@forest-PC:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
forest@forest-PC:~$
```

It's also in the profile file:

```
$ cat /etc/profile
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

export JAVA_HOME="/home/forest/.jdks/jdk1.8.0_261"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

And in IntelliJ IDEA its also set:
[image]
[image]

With Android studio, the exact same problem is present.

IntelliJ console `env` also has $JAVA_HOME set.

```
forest@forest-PC:~/projects/fluttertanulas/myapp$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/forest/.jdks/jdk1.8.0_261
forest@forest-PC:~/projects/fluttertanulas/myapp$ echo $PATH
/home/forest/.jdks/jdk1.8.0_261/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/forest/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/forest/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
forest@forest-PC:~/projects/fluttertanulas/myapp$ 
forest@forest-PC:~/projects/fluttertanulas/myapp$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I just installed everything, from `java` through `android`, `flutter`, `dart` etc. and I just set my `.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`, I just needed a clean restart on the system to make it work. Probably something about how IDEA gets env variables.

Comment: Not IDEA, but the system you are using. .profile is loaded on login, .bashrc is loaded when you open a terminal window.

Comment: The key form me was the restart.